# Should you update child states based on the parent?

Tags: database-design, application-design

I have the following table structure

Event --* Session --* Membership

- An event can be cancelled - reflected via a status column
- A Session can be cancelled - reflected via a status column
- A user can attend or leave an event via the membership row

**My design questions**

If an event is cancelled, should all of the session rows be marked as cancelled as well?

Likewise, if a session is cancelled should the membership row also be marked as cancelled?

What are the pros and cons to these methods?

Answer (score 1):

It's opinion based, but I would err on the side of updating the bare minimum when a status changes.

- If you cancel an event and only update the *Event* row indicating cancelled then you minimize the amount of data that would need to be updated *should* the *event* be reinstated.
- Likewise, if you cancel a session, and only update the *Session* row indicating cancelled then you minimize the amount of data that would need to be updated _should the *session* be reinstated.
- As [Joe W](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/73344/joe-w) points out in a comment:

> if you do update the sessions as well if there was sessions canceled
>   for other reasons you would have a harder time getting the status
>   correct if you un-cancel an event as you might not know exactly which
>   sessions should still be canceled.